# TYPO3 add text to images in php, not TS, frontend plugin

Tags: php, image, typo3, typoscript

I need to place text on top of an image and create a thumbnail. It is a lot of markers for Google Maps with numbers on it.

Based on comment below I could understand that there is no "addTextToImage()" but the GIFBUILDER is the way to go. So I got some help from a collegue and ended up with this result that works fine. Read more about the functions and settings in here:

- http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsbyex/0.0.16/view/6/3/
- http://wiki.typo3.org/GIFBUILDER

The following example uses a marker for Google 21x22px. Using a png the final image ended up with white background. Using a gif the image created did have a transparent backgroup. It may be a server setting and not a general problem.

Here is the code with short comments

```
// create marker
$path = 'fileadmin/templates/matchoffice/images/mapPointer.gif'; // gif on transparent backgroupd. If using a png the background cannot be made transparent
$cObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tslib_cObj');
$counter = $gmapsElementCounter; // the number that will be written on each marker

$imgTSConfigThumb['file'] = 'GIFBUILDER';
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['XY'] = '21,22'; // size of final image. In this case same as input file size
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['format'] = 'png';
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['backColor'] = '#ffffff'; // we want it transparent. That is done in next line
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['transparentColor'] = '#ffffff'; // this color to be transparent.... workaround
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['10'] = 'IMAGE';
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['10.']['file'] = $path;
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['10.']['file.']['maxW'] = 21; // just setting them to the size of the input pig
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['10.']['file.']['maxH'] = 22; // just setting them to the size of the input pig
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['10.']['align'] = 'c,c'; // center this layer (left/right))
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20'] = 'TEXT';
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20.']['text'] = $counter; // use counter as text
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20.']['fontFile'] = 'fileadmin/templates/matchoffice/fonts/arial.ttf'; // font for text
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20.']['align'] = 'center'; // center (left/right)
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20.']['offset'] = '0,12'; // move it 0pz to the left and 12px down
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20.']['fontColor'] = 'white'; // text color white
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20.']['fontSize'] = '9';
$imgTSConfigThumb['file.']['20.']['niceText'] = '1'; // don't know, but it did improve the text

$thumbpath = $this->cObj->IMG_RESOURCE($imgTSConfigThumb);
```

Comment: Well, the code seems fine, it mostly works as you said so what's exactly the problem? What's not formatting right and what do you expect? Also, are you sure the source of the problem is not just your redefinition of the `$path` variable on the second line? (you seem to be using already generated image as the source)

Comment: First: I have never done this before and wandered if there was simpler way to do it. Secondly, I have not found a good example and the documentaton is quite hard to follow. Plus my gif's, sorry, png's are pretty far from something that can be used on a customers site.. So I was hoping someone had tried to create icons with text overlay and would share that. Or share a link to a great tutorial about it. core_api is quit tough to follow I think.

Answer (score 0):

question closed - and before that updated to a working final solution

GIFBUILDER seems to be the way to go when adding text to an image. Use the code abouve if you need to do the same thing.